# UFT: using same action multiple times with different params

Tags: parameters, parameter-passing, qtp, hp-uft

Working with HP Unified Functional Testing:

I have one Login action in a test which contains multiple different users. They will be stored in an external excel file.

With `DataTable.Import(FileName)` I can import the excel file into the `GlobalSheet`. And I am also able to use the first row of the DataTable.

I need the Login action for some other tests where it is integrated as a call  to an existing action.

My issue:

How can I change the login credentials (stored in each row of excel file) for each different login scenario when I integrated the login action as a call to an existing action which can't be modified normally?

Comment: Call the script with defined parameters, so that when it runs it knows which set of credentials to use.

Comment: Can you provide the excel file that you use as input. Are the usernames stored there?

Answer (score 1):

You can Iterate all the rows of excel using a for loop and change the login credentials for each iteration of loop.

```
    For i  = 1 to Datatable.GetSheet("Global").GetRowCount
        Datatable.SetCurrentRow(i)
        ......
        ' <Set of code>
        ......
    Next
```

If you want to use login credentials for a particular user, you can have a condition inside for loop and check if username matches the user you want to login, get the credentials from that row and exit loop.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `Datatable` rows starts in 1, not in 0

Comment: Yeah.. you are right. Modified the code. Thanks for pointing it.